# Testing parallel suspend functions in Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function that takes two suspend functions and runs them in parallel, I'm using [Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io) to do this with parZip and either

```
fun <E, R1, R2, R3> combineCalls(
    call1: suspend () -> Either<E, R1>,
    call2: suspend () -> Either<E, R2>,
    combine: (R1, R2) -> R3
): suspend () -> Either<E, R3> = suspend {
    either {
        parZip({ call1().bind() }, { call2().bind() }) { r1, r2 ->
            r1 to r2
        }
    }
}
```

So which ever of call1 or call2 fails first (returns an Either.Left) will cause the other one to be cancelled and that error will be immediately returned.

I want to test this, but I'm not sure how to ensure which call function will return first.

```
    @Test
    fun basicCombinationErrorBoth() = runTest {
        val result = combineCalls({ 400.left() }, {
            delay(100)    
            500.left() 
        })()
        result assertEquals 400.left()
    }
```

I'm using `runTest` so that it doesn't take up actual time (if we have a lot of tests with delays it adds up), but this means the delay is skipped and the test only passes sometimes as it's indeterminate which passed in suspend function returns first.

How can I use runTest and ensure that one suspend function takes more virtual time than the other?

Comment: I don't know Arrow, but you would have to use the overload of `parZip` that accepts a dispatcher, and pass it your test dispatcher from the test scope provided by `runTest` if you want it to use the virtual time. I'm surprised that the delay is actually skipped in your case. I think the `parZip` overload that you're using forces `Dispatchers.Default`

Comment: @Joffrey Ah thanks, I realised I was being an idiot with using the delay and the short circuiting which meant I didn't realise I needed to do this, ended up skipping parZip and just using async await directly